# Stop Timer periodic on other dateTime/NTPTime Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, timer, ntp

I have 2 function that call `NTP` to get local date time. First one is working like a clock using `Timer.periodic` and the second one for get the time when user tapped the button. But when I display the time in the second function its still runing the `Timer.periodic`. How to avoid that? Thanks

My Code:

```
Future<String> getNTPTime() async {
DateTime startDate = await NTP.now();
String currentDate = DateFormat('d MMMM yyyy').format(startDate);
String currentTime = DateFormat('kk : mm : ss').format(startDate);
print('NTP DateTime: $startDate');

if (mounted) {
  setState(() {
    _currentDate = currentDate;
    _currentTime = currentTime;
  });
}}

Future<String> getNTPTimeIn() async {
DateTime ntpTimeIn = await NTP.now();

String timeIn = DateFormat('kk : mm : ss').format(ntpTimeIn);
print('NTP DateTime: $ntpTimeIn');


if (mounted) {
  setState(() {
    _ntpTimeIn = timeIn;
  });
}}
```

and call it in the initState

```
@override
super.initState();
getNTPTime();
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) => getNTPTime());
}
```

when I display the `_ntpTimeIn` the `Timer.periodic` is still running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should implement it.

```
class YourClas extends StatefulWidget{
Timer _timer;

@override
void initState(){
super.initState();
getNTPTime();
_timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) => getNTPTime());
}

@override
void dispose(){
if(_timer.isActive) _timer.cancel();
super.dispose();
}
}
```

Then when user taps the button call `_timer.cancel();` to stop the `Timer`